# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS : SSH signing failed: agent refused operation

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

I have always connected to a remote machine using SSH with a key also used for Git. Since yesterday, I can not connect because of this error message.

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

I tried several solutions including : `ssh-add` then `ssh-add -l`

I also changed the permissions of the two files `id_rsa id_rsa.pub`.

But the problem remains the same.